# Solutions to Unsafe JavaScript attempt?

Tags: javascript

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://starproject.galaxy-games.com/content/play-star-project from frame with URL http://spgame.galaxy-games.com/star_galaxy/File/Game_Main.php. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

SO i get two of these when i'm trying to access this site, aswell as event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future.

How can i solve this?

Comment: Is this your site, or are you accessing someone else's site? To fix the issues you will need access to the source code.

Comment: This is not my site, it's simply a game site that is accessed on my laptop.
How can I do that and what can I do on that?

Answer (score 0):

The owner of the site (presumably galaxy-games.com) needs to correct their Javascript. As an end user there isn't anything you can do.

---

Specifically, Javascript doesn't allow a frame on starproject.x.com to access variables and other objects in a frame on spgame.x.com because it considers they are different sites. This prevents cross-site scripting or "XSS" attacks. It's fixed by including matching `window.domain` statements in the Javascript.

WebKit's `event` object is also objecting to what it's being asked to do, and the code needs to be re-written so it doesn't use `layerX` and `layerY`.

None of this is within the control of end-users.

Comment: I was told that before hand but also to add to detail on my laptop where i received this error at home, works at uni and other public wifi places. Just doesn't work at home